# Error 9 using ReDim Preserve

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

This function returns a error 9, why? I already read couple of similar questions here but nothing really explained me well.

I'm really trying to understand why ReDim Preserve doesnt work in this case because from "j+1" onwards no input is made(i already checked my cells), so isnt overwriting nothing.

Heres the code

```
Function DadosAnoIndenizações()
ReDim dados(1 To 10000, 1 To 2)
j = 0
For i = 5 To 10000
    If (IsNumeric(Worksheets(2).Cells(i, 8).Value) And Not IsEmpty(Worksheets(2).Cells(i, 8).Value)) Then
        Ano = CInt(Right(Worksheets(2).Cells(i, 8).Value, 4))
        SD = Worksheets(2).Cells(i, 11).Value
        j = j + 1
        dados(j, 1) = Ano
        dados(j, 2) = SD
    End If
Next i
ReDim Preserve dados(1 To j, 1 To 2)
DadosAnoIndenizações = dados
End Function
```

Thanks for any help guys

Comment: @tigeravatar why post your answer as comments? ;-)

Comment: @tigeravatar I agree with Mat's Mug, this will be a searched question and posting your answer will help others and therefore is not trivial.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to change the first dimension of the array. Redim preserve can only change the *last* dimension of the array, which is why you're getting the error.  You can find this information listed MSDN's website: [ReDim Statement (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2.aspx), specifically the "Resizing with Preserve" section:

> - **Resizing with Preserve.** If you use **Preserve**, you can resize only the
>     last dimension of the array. For every other dimension, you must
>     specify the bound of the existing array.
>
>   For example, if your array has only one dimension, you can resize that
>     dimension and still preserve all the contents of the array, because
>     you are changing the last and only dimension. However, if your array
>     has two or more dimensions, you can change the size of only the last
>     dimension if you use **Preserve**.

Typically the way around that is to have the first dimension be your `1 to 2` and the second dimension be your `1 to j` and then do a `Application.Transpose` when writing the results to the worksheet.